# Understanding how natives speak with multiple subjects (Mandarin)

Tags: mandarin

In English, if I wanted to say: "**Today I practiced Chinese with an employee**" the other subject (employee) can properly come last in the sentence. Of course I can also say "**Me and an employee practiced Chinese today**.

However, my understanding in Chinese is that subjects typically appear in the beginning. So I would assume Chinese version is "**今天我和一个员工练习中文**." -- or something like that. Is this indeed true?

And which of these are most common to combine subjects? **和**, **跟**, **给**, **与**

Can someone help explain proper usage of speaking when multiple subjects appear in sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**和 = 跟 = 与** = and/along with. 和 has the most uses; 跟 is used in causal conservation, and the use of 与 is rare, especially in speech, but in older literature, lyrics, or formal writing.

- 今天我**和/跟/与**一个员工练习中文. - Today I practiced Chinese with an employee.

**给** means "give; provide" - 今天我给员工們上了一課 (Today I gave/provide a lesson to the employees, or Today I taught the employees a lesson.)

Comment: Ok this makes sense, however, I'm unaware of this usage of **上了** to mean teaching or providing. Can you explain a little further on this? I'm aware of `上班` to be a verb to Work, and `上学` to be the same for going to school, but seeing `上` by itself threw me off. Thank you.

Comment: It is topic specific. Wife (a teacher): "我要給學生去上課了" - I've to go **teach** (the students/class) now = I've to go to class (**to teach**) now.  Me: "我要去上班了" - I've to go **work** now = I've to go to the office [**to work**] now. Son: "我要去上學/課了" = I'm going to school/class [**to learn**] now. The words in [ ] are redundant but represent the actions depending on the status of the speaker. Teacher - to teach; Worker - to work; Student - [to the place to learn/be taught]. 了 means you did that (in the past); the action is completed (taught vs teach)..

Answer (score 1):

Change employee for him to make life easier.

Today I practised Chinese with him.
今天我和他一起练习汉语。

Colloquial:
Me and him practised Chinese together today.
Him and I practised Chinese together today.

But you probably wouldn't say:

*Me practised Chinese today.
*Him practised Chinese today.

Prepositional phrases are often called complements in Western Grammar. Complements add information. Complements may be omitted. In my opinion [和他一起] is just that, information about the practise.

今天我练习汉语。
今天我[和他一起]练习汉语。
今天他[和我一起]练习汉语。

I suppose, below, you could call "我和他" a double subject, but then, if they are both the subject, who did they meet?

我和他见面。

Extend that:
我和他是在90年代遇见的。